# crossing axes with ultrachart from infragistics?

Tags: c#, infragistics, axes

I would like to have crossing axis on my ultrachart (infragistics product , wpf). I am coding c# , any idea ?

I searched for "crossingaxis" however it seems that this can applied only for polar chart.

Comment: UltraChart instead of ultragraph maybe? CrossingAxis instead of crossing axes probably?! What do you want exactly and what have you tried so far? Put some effort into your question if you expect elaborate answers.

Comment: The UltraChart is a windows forms control and your post says that you are using WPF.  Can you clarify which chart control you are using.  Is it the UltraChart in a WindowsFormsHost or the WPF XamDataChart?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for but as i understand the docs, all Charts including the UltraChart have an [Axis class](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2010.1/CLR3.5/html/Infragistics3.Wpf.Chart.v10.1~Infragistics.Windows.Chart.Axis_members.html) which have a [Crossing](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2010.1/CLR3.5/html/Infragistics3.Wpf.Chart.v10.1~Infragistics.Windows.Chart.Axis~Crossing.html) property.